# The result of gyroscope sensor Android

Tags: android, sensors, gyroscope

I just did my project for getting data gyroscope sensor. If I put my handphone on the table horizontally, the result of gyroscope sensor are :
Roll (X) : 5.326322E-7
Pitch (Y) : 5.326322E-7
Yaw (Z)  : 5.326322E-7

Logically, the result should be 0, because the handphone lay on the table. So,anybody can help me? I give my code below. Thank you very much for the response in advance :).

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE)
    {


        float roolX = event.values[0];
        float pitchY = event.values[1];
        float yawZ = event.values[2];

        koordinatrollX.setText("Orientation X (Roll) :" + Float.toString(event.values[0]));
        koordinatpitchY.setText("Orientation Y (Pitch) :" + Float.toString(event.values[1]));
        koordinatyawZ.setText("Orientation Z (Yaw):" + Float.toString(event.values[2]));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E-7 = 10^-7 so it's very close to 0. You can't expect the hardware to be perfect calibrated or the table to be perfect flat. You could let the user recalibrate based on the surface the phone is at but the result you get is already very close to zero.

Comment: oh i'm sorry. the results are all -5.326322E-7, it should 0 or almost 0. but in fact, it gets negative results.

Comment: @user2080041 it still doesn't matter, the result is still almost 0. Your sensors are very precise so this result should be read as 0.